# modify and save csv file in python

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv, python-3.5

I  have  a   csv file  which has the   first  row  as  column names.

I am  trying to  generate  a  new   csv file   from the  old one   .

The   new   csv file  is obtained by  filtering the   original  csv  file  by    the   second column whose  value  is   HR

Here  is the  code

```
import csv
import os
Filename = os.getenv("HOMEDRIVE") + os.getenv("HOMEPATH") + "\\Desktop\RosterUnified.csv"
Filename1=os.getenv("HOMEDRIVE") + os.getenv("HOMEPATH") + "\\Desktop\RosterCurrentMonth.csv"
f1=open(Filename,'r',newline='\n')
f2=open(Filename1,'w',newline='\n')
reader = csv.DictReader(f1)
writer = csv.writer(f2)
rows = [row for row in reader if row[1] == 'HR']
for row in rows:
    writer.writerow(row)
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

I am getting the  error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dasa17\Desktop\testcsv.py", line 9, in <module>
    rows = [row for row in reader if row[1] == 'HR']
  File "C:\Users\dasa17\Desktop\testcsv.py", line 9, in <listcomp>
    rows = [row for row in reader if row[1] == 'HR']
KeyError: 1
```

Sample from the   csv file, the  shifts  B,WO etc  corresponds to  dates

```
Manager NT ID    Vertical Org   Employee ID 12/1/2016   12/2/2016   12/3/2016   12/4/2016   12/5/2016

johnyv  GS Finance  banakv  B   B   WO  WO  B
johnyv  GS Finance  anbazh  B   B   WO  WO  B
johnyv  GS Finance  immana  B   B   WO  WO  B
immana  GS Finance  raosha  B   B   WO  WO  B
chinj   GS Finance  johnyv  B   B   WO  WO  B
johnyv  GS Finance  yeddub  B   B   WO  WO  B
johnyv  GS Finance  sharmr25    B   B   WO  WO  B
chinj   GS Finance  pellan      B   WO  WO  B
johnyv  GS Finance  ccl B   B   WO  WO  B
johnyv  GS Finance  raos27  B   B   WO  WO  B
johnyv  GS Finance  chinns3 B   B   WO  WO  B
gopals5 IT  guntuv1 B   B   WO  WO  B
goganp  IT  vasuds2 G   G   WO  WO  G
sharmr1 IT  konakr  G   G   C   C   WO
mangan  IT  kanumr  B   B   WO  WO  B
singho1 IT  nanjad  G   G   G   G   G
goganp  IT  tandok  G   G   WO  WO  G
sharmr1 IT  ranjas2 D   WO  A   A   B
mangan  IT  poddar2 A   A   A   A   A
wongs2  IT  subras24    G   G   WO  WO  G
singho1 IT  sevakm  G   G   G   G   G
sharmr1 IT  gopalh  B   B   WO  WO  A
mangan  IT  ramakp2 B   B   B   B   B
cohna1  IT  perumk  B   B   WO  WO  B
ramosj6 IT  maddib  G   G   WO  WO  G
singho1 IT  guptar29    G   G   G   G   G
darisr  IT  vasudl  G   G   WO  WO  G
thangk  IT  singhs70    L   L   WO  WO  L
subras16    IT  hampas  A   A   A   A   A
gordos7 IT  subras16    B   B   B   B   B
omahoc  IT  royd1   G   G   WO  WO  G
darisr  IT  gandhn5 G   G   WO  WO  G
eranhm  IT  arasap  G   G   WO  WO  G
juszkw  IT  patilg2 B   B   WO  WO  B
mkulkarn    IT  kembhp  G   G   WO  WO  G
chavvp  IT  pinnas1 G   G   WO  WO  G
subras16    IT  dhanam  A   A   A   A   A
vasudl  IT  saralm  A   A   A   WO  A
mkulkarn    IT  sukumk1 G   B   WO  WO  B
arorag  IT  sreedr  G   G   WO  WO  G
subras16    IT  sivasm2 B   B   B   B   B
parvar  IT  razdak  B   B   WO  WO  L
vasudl  IT  jayacs1 B   B   WO  WO  A
palang1 IT  vedagm  B   B   B   B   B
mkulkarn    IT  kur5    G   G   WO  WO  G
sharmr1 IT  sambaa1 A   D   WO  WO  B
chavvp  IT  rangak3 G   G   WO  WO  G
arorag  IT  suryaa1 G   G   WO  WO  G
subras16    IT  kumarr27    B   B   B   B   B
Royd1   IT  gavria  G   G   WO  WO  G
```

The file  was   created using the  code

```
d=open(Filename, 'w',newline='\n') #Format for CSV  input
    c = csv.writer(d)
    c.writerow(["Manager NT ID"," Vertical Org","Employee ID" ]+ dayssl)# Write  the  header list of strings  in the  first row
    for row in result_IT:
        c.writerow(row)#Write output for IT to csv
    d.close()


    e=open(Filename, 'a',newline='\n')

    f= csv.writer(e)
    for row in result_Others:
        f.writerow(row)# Append to the  existing  CSV file with non IT data 
    e.close()
    #Close the  CSV  file
```

Comment: Are there any blank lines in your `csv`?  you may have to open it with `newline=''`, like the docs recommend.  Or change your comp to `rows = [row for row in reader if row and row[1] == 'HR']`

Comment: Sample lines (first 5-10 lines) from your csv file?

Comment: @Mohammad Yusuf Ghazi   added

Comment: @Patrick Haugh   no there  are  no   blank spaces

Comment: @ananda what are those dates doing there in the first column? You have 8 columns in data rows and 12 columns in header row.

Comment: @Mohammad Yusuf Ghazi  the   dates  are there   in the  imput   csv file, they  are  the coulmn names,  for 30 days   in a month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot see why you are using a DictReader. You are trying to access the second column so would have needed to use something like `row['NT']`, i.e. you would access it using the header name rather than its position. Using a standard CSV reader, you can just use the position.

I would recommend you make use of Python's `with` statement for accessing files which ensures the file is automatically closed afterwards (no need for a `close()` statement). You could also use [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html?highlight=os.path.join#os.path.join) to append your path components together as follows:

```
import os
import csv

input_filename = os.path.join(os.getenv("HOMEDRIVE"), os.getenv("HOMEPATH"), r"Desktop\RosterUnified.csv")
output_filename = os.path.join(os.getenv("HOMEDRIVE"), os.getenv("HOMEPATH"), r"Desktop\RosterCurrentMonth.csv")

with open(input_filename, newline='\n') as f_input, open(output_filename, 'w', newline='\n') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    #csv_output.writerow(next(csv_input))        # optionally copy over the header

    for row in csv_input:
        if row[1] == 'HR':
            csv_output.writerow(row)
```

This will result in a CSV output file containing only rows with `HR` in the second column. If you also need the header, just uncomment the line.

By working a row at time, it will work with any file size by avoiding loading the whole file into memory at once.

Comment: ,@Martin Evans  I  tried  the   code , it rerturns  a blank (0 kb) csv  output

Comment: The data you have given does not contain any records with `HR` in the second column. As a test, try changing the test to give you `IT` records, e.g.`if row[1] == 'IT':`

Comment: yes, works flawlessly, my   mistake  in including a filter   that was   not available. Thanks  Much  !!

Comment: _Using a standard CSV reader, you can just use the position._ Actually, if you inform the fieldnames, you can access them by the name :)

Comment: btw, csv.reader and csv.writer are essentially wrappers for DictReader and DictWriter :)

Comment: No, `DictReader` is a wrapper for the underlying `reader` instance, check out the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html?highlight=dictreader#csv.DictReader).

Answer (score 0):

Uness you have a strong reason not to, just use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

filename_1 = os.getenv("HOMEDRIVE") + os.getenv("HOMEPATH") + "\\Desktop\RosterUnified.csv"
filename_2 = os.getenv("HOMEDRIVE") + os.getenv("HOMEPATH") + "\\Desktop\RosterCurrentMonth.csv"

df_1 = pd.read_csv(filename_1, sep='\t', skip_blank_lines=True)
df_2 = df_1[df_1['NT'] == 'HR']

df_2.to_csv(filename_2, sep='\t', index=False)
```

If `filename_1` is delimited by spaces instead of tabs, pass `sep=' *'` instead of `sep='\t'` to `read_csv`.

Answer (score 0):

About the `KeyError`:

Essentially, the exception occurred because Python thinks you are trying to access the column nammed "1" in the last line:

```
reader = csv.DictReader(f1)
writer = csv.writer(f2)
rows = [row for row in reader if row[1] == 'HR']
```

This happens because you are using `DictReader` and by your CSV snippet, the allowed columns are the ones that appear in the first row of your CSV file.

If possible, I highly recommend you to use ";" or "," as your column delimiter to make things easier